# What is the difference between UINavigationController.presentViewController and self.presentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Suppose I have a navigation controller with root view controller A, and I need to present a view controller B, I can do with either of the following two ways:

1. `self.navigationController!.presentViewController(b, animated: true)`

or

2. `self.presentViewController(b, animated: true)`

But, I just wonder, what is the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are analogous - both initiate a modal presentation.

In recent iOS versions, modal presentation always travels to the top most container view controller. So when your view controller (aka `self`) is container inside a navigation controller (aka `self.navigationController`), when you attempt presenting on the view controller, it will pass the presentation duties to the navigation controller. You can verify this by logging the `presentingController` of `b` once the presentation is completed. In both cases, `presentingController` will be the navigation controller.

Comment: so, to point of view of B, the difference is what is the `presentingController` pointed to, right? and any other difference, e.g. the UI effect about these two lines of codes.

Comment: In both cases, `presentingController` will be the navigation controller.

Comment: when you present a view controller from a nav controller, UIKit removes other controllers view from the window and also UIKit itself put them back to the window before  presented view get visible

Comment: @Rafeeq I have no idea what you just said.